# How to restrict repos access by user

Tags: azure-devops

We have a project with multi-teams/users and would like to restrict access the available repositories.

Let say I have 3 repos in my project:

- Team A will work on repo 1
- Team B will work on repo 2
- Team C will work on repo 3

How to make sure Team A won't be able to see repos 2 and 3, for example?

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the security settings available at the repository level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the security settings on the individual repos.

Because permissions are evaluated as **Deny** trumps **Allow** in the entire inheritance chain, you would add the teams to the repo and deny their "Contribute" permission.

### Deny DSP team

[image]

### Allow ULP team

[image]

Note: If you add a team to a repo, and their permissions are the same as any team or group that team is a member of, the entry for the team will be removed because no explicit values were given that the team or group cannot inherit.

This can be observed by the **Remove** button being disabled. AzDO is telling you that this team or group doesn't have explicit permissions set and all its permissions are either inferred (Not Set) or inherited, and thus will be removed.

[image]